# pyinstaller: doesn't save the video from the webcam

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, pyinstaller

I have a python script which records the webcam and saves the video using cv2.VideoWriter. The code works with no issues when I run it directly. After creating an exe file on windows using pyinstaller, it opens the webcam and creates output.avi, but the file doesn't open. This is my sample.py script:

```
import cv2

# Set up video capture
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
video_out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 12.0, (640, 480))

# Record video and audio
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    video_out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release resources
video_out.release()
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Then I ran the following command in terminal:

```
pyinstaller --onefile sample.py
```

I also added opencv_videoio_ffmpeg412_64.dll to the folder next to sample.exe as other people suggested and still same issue exists. I even tried this command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile sample2.py --add-binary opencv_videoio_ffmpeg412_64.dll;.
```

still no luck. Any suggestions please?

Comment: `assert video_out.isOpened()` -- pyinstaller probably fails to package all OpenCV library dependencies, which includes ffmpeg. the code then fails silently because you didn't check `isOpened()`. -- one workaround is to ask for `.avi` and `MJPG`. this is built into OpenCV and always available.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for your response. Do you mind showing me where and how to use video_out.isOpened() ? thanks

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think the connection is opened, because sample.avi is created but no frames get stored in it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: yes, all the error checking of both the VideoCapture and VideoWriter. opencv will not throw exceptions.

Comment: your code works fine for me before and after compiling with pyinstaller

Comment: @Alexander thanks for looking into this. What's your OS and Python version? Mine is Windows 11 and Python 3.7.

Comment: Same OS but I am using 3.10 , are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @Alexander good point. No I wasn't using it. I'll activate one and re-do the process. Will keep you posted. thanks.